# Integrating Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to install Firebase in React Native. But I wasn't able to get the process right. Can anyone please tell me the full correct way of integrating firebase in React Native( NOT EXPO ).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase#readme)
and for full documentation you can visit [here](https://rnfirebase.io/).

If you are starting to integrate firebase and also you are new with React Native then you should consider the [starter kit](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter) from react-native-firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-native-firebase-tutorial/amp/) by Florian Marcy quite useful where there are steps to create a firebase project, a react native app and then subsequently the integration part.

You can refer this if you are looking for an end-to-end process.